# Volume of $E=\{5x^8 \le y \le 7x^8; 2y^5 \le z \le 3y^5; z^7 \le x \le 6z^7\}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am stuck with the following problem:

Compute volume of $E=\{5x^8 \le y \le 7x^8; 2y^5  \le z  \le 3y^5; z^7 \le x \le 6z^7\}$.

My progress:

It is easy to see that $x,y,z \ge 0$. Therefore I can add all inequalities and after simple algebra get the following: $$5x^8 + 2y^5+z^7 \le x+y+z \le 7x^8 + 3y^5+6x^7$$
Update: as it was pointed out by A.Γ. adding inequalities does not work because different sets can give the same inequalities. So, it looks like I should solve or at least get some kind of information for integration directly from the system somehow.

Any hint?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The first idea is wrong for sure - the single inequality is true for large $x,y,z$  and gives en unbounded region while $E$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, of course you are right, I updated my ideas.

Comment: No, when you add inequalities you lose information. Look - if you add instead another inequalities $E'=\{ 5x^8 \le \color{red}x \le 7x^8; 2y^5  \le \color{red}y  \le 3y^5; z^7 \le \color{red}z \le 6z^7\}$ you get *exactly* the same sum as before. Do you think that $E=E'$?

Comment: I think that $E \neq E'$. Ok, adding them does not work. So I should somehow solve this system to obtain borders, right?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** the set is given by 
$$
\begin{cases}
5\le\frac{y}{x^8}\le 7,\\
2\le\frac{z}{y^5}\le 3,\\
1\le\frac{x}{z^7}\le 6
\end{cases}\quad\rightarrow\quad\text{substitution}\quad\rightarrow\quad
\begin{cases}
5\le u\le 7,\\
2\le v\le 3,\\
1\le w\le 6
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for hint. It is getting closer. Unfortunately I do not see how to perform the substituion. Can you give a hint at least for the first inequality.

Comment: @Hedgehog $y=ux^8$, $z=vy^5$, $x=wz^7$ $\Rightarrow$ $$x=wz^7=wv^7y^{5\cdot 7}=wv^7u^{5\cdot 7}x^{5\cdot 7\cdot 8}\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=...$$

Comment: Thanks. I think I am able to move forward by myself now. I will post my calculations a bit later today. As long as they are correct and the problem is solved, I will accept you answer. Thanks a lot for your hints!